# MediaPlayer Play/Stop in Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

Situation:

I have an app that has a custom listview for a couple of elements and these elements have a Play button to play corresponding media. In itself, this works great.
I decided, it might be a good idea to be able to stop playback of a clip, so I added a Stop button to each listview item, but set visibility to GONE until something is playing.

Code:

```
        ImageButton bplay = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_bplay);
        bplay.setTag(currentClip.getFile());
        bplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finalItemView.findViewById(R.id.item_bplay).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finalItemView.findViewById(R.id.item_bstop).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mp.release();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), currentClip.getFile());
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        finalItemView.findViewById(R.id.item_bplay).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        finalItemView.findViewById(R.id.item_bstop).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                });
            }
        });

        ImageButton bstop = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_bstop);
        bstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.release();
                finalItemView.findViewById(R.id.item_bplay).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                finalItemView.findViewById(R.id.item_bstop).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Description:

This works fine, as long as the user concentrates on one clip only. The Play button gets replaced with the Stop button, the Stop button stops the clip, or if you let the clip run out, the buttons switch back as well.

Problem:

If the user decides to interrupt playback by hitting Play on the second element in the list, the first one will get stuck with a Stop button. Since the Stop button just does mp.release(), the first element's stop button is now capable of stopping playback of the second clip.
Since this is all happening in a listview, when the second item is clicked, I no longer have access to the first one to replace the buttons again.
I looked for a method to catch an interruption (much like the mp.setOnCompletionListener looks for the successful completion) and reset the buttons, but so far, I couldn't come up with anything.
I actually like the fact that by putting release first, then creating a new mediaplayer and then starting it, the user is able to switch between clips quickly by just pressing Play on another clip. I just want the Stop button on the original clip to disappear, once a new clip is started.

Questions:

- How do I catch, when the user decides to switch to another clip without stopping the first one?
- Does my approach of switching out buttons make sense at all? Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If you make a service that handles the MediaPlayer, you can send intents to it to control the play/stop. In the play intent, you can include a PendingIntent that the service sends back to the UI when the currently playing media is stopped for any reason, either by completion or if some other clip is started.

The PendingIntent is generated by the onClick callback for the list item, so it will automatically call the correct list item callback and reset the button.

Answer (score 0):

- How do I catch, when the user decides to switch to another clip without stopping the first one?

I think setOnCompletionListener may be a good idea, but instead of release() you should call stop() method. If it won't help you can also just skip stream to very end ( seekTo(getDuration ()) method ). This definietly will call onCompletionListener

- Does my approach of switching out buttons make sense at all? Are there better alternatives?

I think you don't need to use ImageButton. Add to your Adapter "selected" field, where you remember number of last selected item. In getView() you can check some row is "selected" and make appropriate image (play/pause) visible. Then add OnItemClickListener interface to your Adapter class. When onItemClick method is called, check if the same (then pause stream and make "selected" field null) or new (then play stream and assign new row number to "selected" field)  row was selected. Make notifyDataSetChanged() method call to generate new rows with correct images in your list view.

Comment: The OnCompletionListener does not get, when there is an interruption by another item, as each Play call begins with mp.release() the previous mp instance is just cancelled.

Comment: Also, I do need the ImageButton, since the items consist of a textview and four ImageButtons in a custom listview, I don't just want the item to play, if the list item is clicked.
What I meant by the question was: Is it easier to replace the drawable and method for one button to toggle Play and Stop with the same button, or does it make more sense to have a separate Play and Stop button, but through VISIBLE and GONE only ever show one to the user in the exact same position.

Comment: To the user, it doesn't make a difference, they see a Play Button and once they click it, there is a Stop button in the same spot, but the approach in Java is existentially different, that's why I asked. I wasn't planning on ditching the entire layout that users have gotten used to.